# regex - prevent two characters from being adjacent

Tags: php, regex, eclipse

I need to replace all PHP lines that are like `<?=[something]?>` with this: `<?php echo [something]; ?>` The problem is that there can be almost anything in that **something** clause even **?** and **<** but they can't be adjacent. I am kinda new to regexes and wrote this very messy expression: `\<\?\=([a-zA-Z0-9()=#<>\[\]\\/'"._$\?:, \-]*)([;]*)\?\>` and replaced it with `<?php echo \1; ?>`.

It works but it can't match something like this:

`<?=[something]?><tr><td><?=[something]?>` when it's all in one line. It matches the whole line altogether.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to do that? And why don't you just change `<?=` to `<?php echo `? Why do you need to match the remaining content at all? You don't even need a regex for that. A simple `str_replace` will do (given that you want to do that with PHP and not with `sed` anyway)

Comment: You should try using Reluctant quantifier instead of greedy. Greedy quantifier will match as much as it finds to satisfy the entire pattern to match. Try making the `*` quantifier on your character class to `*?`.

Comment: You're complicating things, just to a global search/replace from `<?=` to `<?php echo`, don't need regex for this.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I thought of that, but my boss is very strict in things and the current code is very messy and if I do the replacement that you said, some line will end up with not having a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$s = '<?=[something]?><tr><td><?=[something]?>';
$s = preg_replace('/(<\?)=\s*(\[[^]]*\])\s*(\?>)/', '$1php echo $2; $3', $s);
var_dump($s);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(56) "<?php echo [something]; ?><tr><td><?php echo [something]; ?>"
```